# Does there exists a onto continuos function $f\colon (0,1) \to[0,1]$ which is one to one .

Tags: real-analysis

Iam trying to solve this problem , i can visualize graphically it is not possible. iam trying to do the proof by contradiction. if f:(0,1) to [0,1] is a continuos onto function  then i have to prove that f can never be 1-1 . so iam letting that if f is 1-1 then either f is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing function. so case (1) if f is strictly increasing function then there exits some t in (0,1) such that f(t)=0 , so for x lesser than t f(x)k , f(x) <0 which is also not possible .so f can't be 1-1 . My method is right ??? is there is any alternative approach then plz tell

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE! For future reference, [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) can be used to format equations.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279435/prove-that-if-a-continuous-function-is-injective-then-it-is-monotonic)

Comment: Hint: Let $f\colon (0,1)\to [0,1]$ be continuous and surjective. Take $a=f^{-1}(0)$ and $b=f^{-1}(1)$. Prove that $f([c,d])=[0,1]$ using the intermediate value theorem, where $c=min(a,b)$ and $d=max(a,b)$. Conclude that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Informally: if $f(x) = 1$ then $x$ is a local maximum of $f$ which implies $f$ cannot be one-to-one on any neighborhood of $x$.  It would then be possible to formalize the last part (local maximum implies not one-to-one) using the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is merely an elaboration of the solution provided by Júlio Cesar under the original comment (all credit to him), which is in itself "only" making precise your original correct reasoning.

Assume $f:(0,1) \to [0,1]$ was continuous and *bijective*. Then we find *unique* $a := f^{-1}(0)$, $b := f^{-1}(1)$ and may assume wLog that $0 < a < b < 1$. Choose $x \in (0,a)$ and let $y := f(x) \in [0,1]$. By the *intermediate value theorem*, we find some $c \in (a,b)$ with $f(c) = y = f(x)$. Since $x < a < c$, $f$ is not injective, so we arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

$[0,1] $ is closed.

$f $ continuous and one to one implies $f^{-1}([0,1]) $ is closed.

this is not the case for $(0,1) $

Using sequential characterisation of the limit, it is easy to prove the continuity of $f^{-1} $.

Comment: Strictly speaking, You would need to know, however, that $f^{-1}$ is a continuous function (this is true but requires more work than the reasoning from the OP).

Comment: But $(0,1)$ is closed in itself...

Comment: He probably means closed as a subset of $\mathbb R$ (not in its own subspace topology).

Comment: That is what I am suspecting. Or perhaps he/she is really caring about compactness.

Comment: @Berni "He" may be "She" too... (I think so)

Comment: Regardless, in order to show that $f^{-1}([0,1])$ would be compact, continuity of the inverse function is key. The comments below the original post suggest a far more appropriate, elementary way to show that such $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: She must have meant **compact** instead of *closed*.

Comment: It is if $f^{-1}$ is itself a continuous function.

Comment: is  there an example with $f $ from an interval $I $ to $J $ continuous and $f^{-1} $ not.

Comment: Any continuous, bijective function $f: I \to J$ between two subsets of $\mathbb R$ has a continuous inverse. But this is special to such subsets and *cannot* be generalised to functions between between arbitrary topological spaces. You usually proof it by showing first that such $f$ must be strictly monotone on its connected components.